# npm package breaks removing outdated files

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I've been developing an npm package for my dev team.  I added a json file that I no longer need, but when I remove it and republish the package it breaks because it can't find the file (not called anywhere in the package)
Anybody know how to remove it without breaking the package?

Comment: Is said file referenced in your [`package-lock.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-lock-json) file?

Comment: Can you please post any relevant code and the error messages and/or logs?